# I need to edit a existing form in plone

Tags: plone

I've never used plone but I need to edit a form to add a field. I've already looked everywhere but I can't find anything to do this, is there `portal_type`?

It's a big problem we have on my company, last programmer ran away and left us with Plone :\

Thanks.

Comment: Wich Form want you edit? Standard Contact Form or a Login Form or whatever. Please specify your Question. We need more Informations. Please tell us the Version of Plone. Look at [Plone Form Docs](http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/forms/z3c.form.html) Plone use z3c Form Schemas.

Comment: Hi, its a form where we can add some files, I need to add an extra field on this camp, I know it's a portal_type='File' but I've no idea where I can edit it to add an extra field, the client want a thumbnail on each files ( its a form to add some pdf on the website)

Answer (score 1):

1. Look at your URL, find the Name View, the last Part of url, e.g /fileupload-form
2. Search with grep on the Commandline in your Productfolder to the Name, you can find a Browserview with the Name 'fileupload-form'
3. Look at the Definition in the zcml-File you can find the Classdefinition of View/Form
4. Search the Interface of Form, it could be defined like:

```py
class IMyForm(form.Schema):
    """ Define form fields """

    name = schema.TextLine(
            title=u"Your name",
        )
```

5. add a new Field of Type NamedBlobFile or NamedFile, look in the Documentation [Example](http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/forms/files.html#simple-upload-form-example)

Comment: Hi there,

url: http://zeus.paloalto.pt/Site_isptec/pt/newsletter/portal_factory/File/file.2016-04-14.4850140009/edit

So I think I've to search for the "file" view?

Comment: Ok, looks like ATFile Type creation. You need two Fileupload-Fields in the Contenttype File? When yes, that ist not possible. You can't add a "Oneliner" to extend the ATFile Type.
Create your own Contenttype or add a Folder that includes two Files. Thats dirty, but you have a Container that holds two Files. Or install Dexterity Framework and create your contenttype TTW. Be aware, check your Plone Version. Tipp, create Contentitems TTW is build-in in Plone5 and supported in Plone 4.

Comment: I've no idea of what your are saying :( 

Where can I start?

Comment: the first request of the client is to swith the "list view" to a view with "tumbnails"... to start, if I had a static image for the thumbnail, where do I change the view type?

Comment: The View of Folder, wich contain your Files, can change in the Menu called like "View". Select Album View or Gallery View. You have started a [Thread](https://community.plone.org/t/help-really-needed/1961) with the same Problem, Please let us discuss not on two Plattforms. Plone Community is ok.